# How to get closest element of a class to a function call using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, e-commerce

**Problem:** I have a simple storefront on my website which allows users to select a quantity and then add to cart. The problem I am experiencing is when a user adds to cart, the function is grabbing the first `<select> <option>` in the html file. The result is that any item added to the cart is being added by the first selectors quantity. I am avoiding using ids and passing them to the function because at some point all storefront items would be dynamically loaded in.
This is my first web development experience.

**Expected Result:** When selecting a quantity for an item and adding to cart, the quantity should be dependent on the "nearest" quantity.

**My Understanding:** In my `addQty();` function below the `var e = document.getElementByClassName("qty);"` should get the closest "qty" class to the function call. I am at a loss of how to do that.

**Code:** The following is what an item card html looks like (there are multiple item cards) and the JS function I have written.

**HTML*

```
<div class="card-footer">
    <select class="qty">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="addQty();">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
function addQty()
{
  var e = document.getElementClassName("qty");
  var qty = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var s =
  {
    //Reset the cart session  to remove everything added to the cart previously.
    'reset':true,
    //Define the product path(s) and the quantity to add.
    'products' : [
      {
        'path':'test-product',
        'quantity': qty
      }
    ],
    'checkout': false
  }
  fastspring.builder.push(s);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

**MY SOLUTION**
I added a productID higher up in the DOM for each product. That is then used in the querySelector() call to identify which select is being referenced.

```
<div class="column" id="test-product-2">
    <div class="card-footer">
        <select class="qty">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="addQty('test-product-2');">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function addQty(product_path)
{
  var selector = "#" + product_path + " .qty";
  var e = document.querySelector(selector);
  //var e = document.closest("qty");
  var qty = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var s =
  {
    //Reset the cart session  to remove everything added to the cart previously.
    'reset': false,
    //Define the product path(s) and the quantity to add.
    'products' : [
      {
        'path':product_path,
        'quantity': qty
      }
    ],
    'checkout': false
  }
  fastspring.builder.push(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to have multiple products on a page and don't want to put an `id` on the `select` tag, you nevertheless will probably want to use a unique ID on a tag at a higher level in the DOM for each product. And also pass that value to your `addQty` function. Then you could use `querySelector`, something like this,:

```
var qtySelect = document.querySelect("#uniqueId .qty");
var qty = qtySelect.options[qtySelect.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've edited my question with my working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using `getElementById`, but the element you're trying to get doesn't have that id. You should either add the id to that element or search by something else, like classname. Here's what the id solution would look like:

```
<div class="card-footer">
    <select class="qty" id="qty">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: My mistake, I edited my code to reflect my working code. That still doesnt answer my original question though unfortunately. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.